# Spring Mongo Template doesn't return data even if exists

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a below structure. When I run query `db.OrganizationAttributeMetaData.find({ "orgid" : 14}).pretty();` using command prompt it returns below data. But when try to fetch it using Spring MongoTemplate using below code it is returning blank data object. Debug log

> 2017-04-17 13:26:31,661 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query: { "orgid" :
>   14} fields: { "attrUniqueCode" : 1 , "attributeName" : 1 , "_id" : 1 ,
>   "metadataVersion" : 1} for class: class
>   com.debopam.amsapp.model.OrganizationAttributeMetaData in collection:
>   OrganizationAttributeMetaData

Method

```
@Override
    public Page<OrganizationAttributeMetaData> searchOrgMetadata(int orgidentifier,String orgHierachyIdentifier,String serachtext,Pageable page) {

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("orgid").is(orgidentifier));

        if(StringUtils.hasText(orgHierachyIdentifier)){
            List<String> orgHierarchyList = com.debopam.amsapp.util.StringUtils.delimitedStringToConcatenatedStringListReversed(orgidentifier+"", AppConstants.ORG_DELIMITER);
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(orgHierachyIdentifier).in(orgHierarchyList));
        }

        if(StringUtils.hasText(serachtext)){
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("attributeName").regex(Pattern.compile(serachtext, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE))
                    .orOperator(Criteria.where("attrUniqueCode").regex(Pattern.compile(serachtext, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE))));
        }

        query.fields().include("attributeName").include("attrUniqueCode").include("id").include("metadataVersion");
        //query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "attrUniqueCode").and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "metadataVersion")));
        query.with(page);

        List<OrganizationAttributeMetaData> orgmetadata = mongoTemplate.find(query, OrganizationAttributeMetaData.class);

        long total = mongoTemplate.count(query, OrganizationAttributeMetaData.class);

        Page<OrganizationAttributeMetaData> orgMetadataPage = new PageImpl<OrganizationAttributeMetaData>(orgmetadata, page, /*(null == answers)?0:answers.size()*/total);
        return orgMetadataPage;
    }
```

Data

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58efd07fb9eb52cb113f21ac"),
        "_class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.OrganizationAttributeMetaData",
        "attributeName" : "ISU",
        "attrUniqueCode" : "ISU",
        "metadataVersion" : 1,
        "htmlAttributes" : {
                "0" : {
                        "isuname" : {
                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLInputTag",
                                "htmlinputclasstype" : "htmlinputtag",
                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                "label" : "Name",
                                "id" : "isuname",
                                "tagName" : "input",
                                "inputtype" : "text",
                                "attributes" : [
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "pattern",
                                                "value" : "",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "readonly",
                                                "value" : "false",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "id",
                                                "value" : "isuname",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "placeholder",
                                                "value" : "ISU Name",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "required",
                                                "value" : "true",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "name",
                                                "value" : "isuname",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                },
                "1" : {
                        "lob" : {
                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLInputTag",
                                "htmlinputclasstype" : "htmlinputtag",
                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                "label" : "LOB",
                                "id" : "lob",
                                "tagName" : "select",
                                "inputtype" : "select",
                                "attributes" : [
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "name",
                                                "value" : "lob",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "name" : "id",
                                                "value" : "lob",
                                                "valueRef" : null
                                        }
                                ],
                                "nestedTags" : [
                                        {
                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLOptionTag",
                                                "htmlinputclasstype" : "htmloptiontag",
                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                "attributes" : [
                                                        {
                                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                                "name" : "Telecom",
                                                                "value" : "Telecom",
                                                                "valueRef" : null
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                                "name" : "Banking",
                                                                "value" : "Banking",
                                                                "valueRef" : null
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                                "name" : "Media & Entertainment",
                                                                "value" : "Media & Entertainment",
                                                                "valueRef" : null
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                                "name" : "Govt.",
                                                                "value" : "Govt.",
                                                                "valueRef" : null
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                                "class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.html.HTMLAttribute",
                                                                "serialVersionUID" : NumberLong(1),
                                                                "name" : "Insurance",
                                                                "value" : "Insurance",
                                                                "valueRef" : null
                                                        }
                                                ]
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        },
        "orgHierachyIdentifier" : "14",
        "orgid" : 14,
        "createDate" : ISODate("2017-04-13T19:24:23.535Z"),
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-04-13T19:24:23.535Z"),
        "createdBy" : "appadmin",
        "lastModifiedBy" : "appadmin"
}
```

Comment: Your query looks good to me. How does your `page` looks like ? `PageRequest(int page,
                   int size)`are  zero indexed. So 0 for page will return first page.

Comment: Sorry I have mistakenly changed it to 1. Thaks for pointing out.